# WebRTC Data Channel with gzip compression

Tags: compression, webrtc, rtcdatachannel

Data are internally compressed with `permessage-deflate`extension before sending to server via WebSocket. What's about WebRTC? Does Data Channel API support compression?

Answer (score 2):

You can send arbitrary binary data over datachannels, so you can certainly deflate/compress data before sending and decompress on the other end.